# from blender 2.83 to unreal extrude problem

Tags: mesh, extrude

i have imported a basic model from blender 2.83 to unreal. Extrude areas looks very bad. I tried shift N and Ctrl A in the blender before export but nothing changed. This problem was not exist in old blenders. It s came to me with 2.83... Is someone knows what is the solution. Thank you so much.[image]

Comment: It looks like you have to UV unwrap your model again after extruding.

Comment: thank you so much. it worked :)